# Get CLI in vmware-server like xm console

Tags: virtualization, command-line-interface, vmware-server

Is there a way to get a command line prompt to a hosted virtual machine in vmware server like `xm console <name>` does in Xen?

I know the graphic UI to conect to vmware-servers but I'm under low latency ssh only access and I need something more "text friendly"

Comment: I take it the VMs aren't networked with SSH, otherwise you'd just SSH to them directly right?

Comment: ssh got locked. I was looking for a "virtual terminal port" like xen console does

Answer (score 1):

http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vcli/

The vSphere Command-Line Interface (vSphere CLI) command set allows you to run common system administration commands against ESX/ESXi systems from any machine with network access to those systems.

Comment: That looks like it's for running commands against ESX, not targeting hosted VMs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://labs.vmware.com/flings/vgc

VGC will let you run commands in guests.  Have tried it on Windows guests, but not on Linux.

Let us know if it works for you.

Comment: Hmmmmpf windows stufff. I'll try it but it will take me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it depends on the guest OS but if it's a *nix variant couldn't you just SSH/Telnet/RDP into it or use powershell if it's Windows?

Comment: Not that day. Mi ssh went unresponsive And I was triying to find another way to log into machine. Using Xen when I put the virtual machine under a firewall or remove ssh and other services I allways have the oportunity to use xen console. And I was looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have VMware tools installed in the guest OS, the API will let you invoke commands. For instance, the VMware PowerCLI command is `Invoke-VmScript.` vMA might have one as well.

Side note: VMware Server is [EOL 2011/06/30](http://www.vmware.com/support/policies/lifecycle/general/index.html).